# Override the chef bash return code

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am running a chef recipie to install Websphere fixpacks. The fixpack retuns and exitcode [2] which is for partial install. Its an expected behaviour, but chef is just taking it as an error. Is there any way to override it.

I want chef to move ahead with the next task, even if the return exit code is [2]

```
================================================================================
Error executing action `run` on resource 'bash[was-install-fixpacks]'
================================================================================


Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
------------------------------------
Expected process to exit with [0], but received '2'
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A quick look into the [documentation](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_bash.html) reveals the parameter `returns`:

> The return value for a command. This may be an array of accepted values. An exception is raised when the return value(s) do not match. Default value: 0.

Example:

```
bash "was-install-fixpacks" do
  command ..
  returns [0, 2]
end
```

Comment: You are absolutely right, did read the returns but wasn't able to understand it properly. Thanks a lot for the clear example.